# JS return an array and an object from function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my react app I have a hook that handles resizing of the screen. The function returns an array of width and height.

```
function useDimensions() {
  const [size, setSize] = useState([window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight]);
  const [isSmScreen, setIsSmScreen] = useState(false);
  const [isLgScreen, setIsLgScreen] = useState(false);

  function handleResize() {
    const windowWidth = window.innerWidth;
    if (windowWidth < BREAKPOINTS.sm) {
      setIsXsScreen(true);
    } else if (windowWidth < BREAKPOINTS.lg) {
      setIsSmScreen(true);
    }

    setSize([window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight]);
  }

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    // So it doesnt get called every pixel changed
    const debouncedResize = debounce(handleResize, 100);

    window.addEventListener('resize', debouncedResize);

    return () => window.removeEventListener('resize', handleResize);
  }, []);

  return size;
}

export default useDimensions;
```

And i call the hook in my react app like `const [width] = useDimensions()`. I also want to call the hook like `const {isSmScreen} = useDimensions()`. Is this possible and how can export it from the useDimensions hook

Comment: removeEventListener should be removing the debouncedResize, not handleResize

Comment: If the goal is to return various named properties, why not return an object instead of an array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, as an array is an object, you can define additional properties.

For instance:

```
size.isSmScreen = isSmScreen;
return size;
```

Or:

```
return Object.assign(size, {isSmScreen});
```

Whether this is a good idea, is debatable though. If I use a function to get an array, I would not expect that array to have other custom properties.

It would be more natural to return the array data as a single property of the returned object, like:

```
return { size, isSmScreen }
```

Then the caller must of course be aware of that. To only get the width, it could do:

```
let { size: [width] } = useDimensions();
```

Comment: I was thinking something along the lines of declaring an array ie, const [width, height] = useDimensions(). And then declaring an object ie: `const {isSmScreen} = useWindowSize()`; 2 separate stuctures declare 2 separate things

Comment: Many options ;-)